# Swift "date from string" conversion doesn't work but the format works with online service?

Tags: swift, string, date, nsdateformatter, dateformatter

Code for playground:

```
var dateStr = "Fri, 03 Aug 2018 08:55:22 GMT"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z")
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateStr)
```

In the same time I use the [online service](http://nsdateformatter.com/) - it shows that the format I chose is correct. Where is my mistake?

Comment: `dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Small tip when you are working with `DateFormatter`, if it doesn't work one way, then do it the other way:

```
let string = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
print("string: \(string)")
```

This way you'll see how your format is really interpreted.

If you do so, you'll get:

```
$> string: Fri, Aug 03, 2018, 12:05:09 GMT
```

See the extras `,`  and the `Aug 03` vs `03 Aug`?

Now, your issue is that you misunderstood `localizedDateFormatFromTemplate`.

In fact you could remove spaces, punctuations and order.
For instance, `dateFormatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("ddyyyyHHmmsszEMMM")` gives the same output.

You just needs to give it what kind of infos you want (day, year, months, etc.), and it create the correct `dateFormat` corresponding in the localized version (adding then extra punctuations, etc.).

So use instead:

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z"
```

Side note: 
I currently live in GMT+2, so I added `dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)` to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give `dateFormatter.dateFormat` to convert the string to date format. From the comment you get the answer but for others i am posting a correct answer here.

```
var dateStr = "Fri, 03 Aug 2018 08:55:22 GMT"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z" //Added this line.
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateStr)
```

Comment: `setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate` is extra at all